# NavigationLinks with various Views destination within one ForEach loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to make ForEach loop in my MainView which would contain NavigationLinks to different Views depending on where user wants to go.
I created enum in order to get names for specific views:

```
enum NavigationViewsNames: String, CaseIterable {
        case orders = "Orders"
        case returns = "Returns"
        case personalInfo = "Personal Info"
        case paymentDetails = "Payment Details"
        case help = "Help"
        
        static var allCases: [NavigationViewsNames] {
            return [
                .orders,
                .returns,
                .personalInfo,
                .paymentDetails,
                .help
            ]
        }
    }
```

And I use switch-case within the view and ForEach to create specific NavigationLinks:

```
VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            ForEach(NavigationViewsNames.allCases, id: \.self) { navigationViewName in
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    NavigationLink() {
                                        switch navigationViewName {
                                        case .orders:
                                            OrdersView()
                                        case .returns:
                                            ReturnsView()
                                        case .personalInfo:
                                            PersonalInfoView()
                                        case .paymentDetails:
                                            PaymentDetailsView()
                                        case .help:
                                            HelpView()
                                        }
                                    } label: {
                                        Button(navigationViewName.rawValue) {
                                        }
                                        .buttonStyle(CustomButton(buttonColor: .white, textColor: .accentColor, onlyStroke: true, strokeColor: .accentColor, rightChevronNavigationImage: true))
                                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
                                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                                    }
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

It results in:

[image]

With all NavigationLinks buttons being clickable however randomly some of them won't lead to any view at one time and at another time they will.

Comment: Instead of using `Navigationlinks` in the `ForEach`, use `Buttons` and allow them to trigger the `Navigationlinks` programmatically in the background of the view.

Comment: @Yrb, could you please explain a little further? I don't know exactly what you mean by triggering NavigationLinks in the background by clicking buttons.

Comment: Loo up "SwiftUI programmatic navigation". Navigation links can be triggered by a bound optional variable. If you have the button set the variable to the correct value, you can trigger a `NavigationLink` that is placed anywhere in the view, but that is hidden from the user. You could reuse your enum for that.

Comment: @Yrb, thank you. I implemented your solution and now it works. I don't know however why the previous one did not work and I would be glad if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: `NavigationLinks` prepare their destinations when the view containing them inits. You can see this if you accidentally have something that is nil at init, but that you know will be non-nil when you click the link. You will crash due to the original nil. Your solution(and I am surprised it compiled) was changing destinations on the fly for a single link. For the limited choices you had, most would just hard code the links in the VStack. You always only have a set number of destinations.

Comment: The reason why it did not function properly with your previous code because every NavigationLink you had contains all cases. It should be one NavigationLink one case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you use `Button` inside `NavigationLink`. `NavigationLink` already is a `Button` so there may be some issues with that as there’s no action for the `Button` itself. So following code may work:

````
VStack(alignment: .center) {
                            ForEach(NavigationViewsNames.allCases, id: \.self) { navigationViewName in
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    NavigationLink() {
                                        switch navigationViewName {
                                        case .orders:
                                            OrdersView()
                                        case .returns:
                                            ReturnsView()
                                        case .personalInfo:
                                            PersonalInfoView()
                                        case .paymentDetails:
                                            PaymentDetailsView()
                                        case .help:
                                            HelpView()
                                        }
                                    } label: {
                                        Text(navigationViewName.rawValue)
                                       
                                    }
                                     .buttonStyle(CustomButton(buttonColor: .white, textColor: .accentColor, onlyStroke: true, strokeColor: .accentColor, rightChevronNavigationImage: true))
                                     .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9)
                                     .contentShape(Rectangle())
                                     .padding(.bottom, 20)

                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
    ```
````